# Do I need to 'keep' Parcelable in proguard rules while obfuscating

Tags: android, proguard, parcelable, android-proguard

My Project has few classes that extends [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).
Do I need to 'keep' them in proguard rules while obfuscating.

What is the general practice for parcelables?

Comment: No. But if you are using the same class for JSON parsing using GSON then use serializedName tag with field name.

Comment: Yes you need, as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918277/3050249

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, the default android rules include this:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR;
}
```

These default rules will be applied if you leave the default generated gradle definition in place:

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: Make sure you do not forget the 'final' in your field definition! That was in my case the reason, why proguard removed it still..

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Kotlin `@Parcelize` with proguard you can add this to  `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-keep @kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize public class *
```

Comment: `kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize` is deprecated in favor of `kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize` so this may need changing to 
`-keep @kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize public class *`