# Why I'm facing Parcelable issues just when minify is true?

Tags: android, proguard, parcelable

My app is working great on debug build variant, but when I put on release, that the only difference is the obfuscation, the app doesn't work well

```
 fun upsertPatient(patient: Patient, onCompletion: (Patient) -> Unit) {
        val px = PatSecHelper.patToN(patient, SecHelper.genKey())
        if (px != null) {
            val subscription = Single.fromCallable {
                val id = patientDao?.insertPatient(px)
                px.id = id
                px
            }
                    ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    ?.subscribe({
                        onCompletion(it!!)
                    }, {
                        BleLogHelper.writeError("Error inserting patient into database", it)
                    })
            subscriptions.add(subscription)
        }
    }
```

On debug mode works fine, but on release its raising a exception on this method above.

```
Unable to find generated Parcelable class for io.b4c.myapp.a.f, verify that your class is configured properly and that the Parcelable class io.b4c.myapp.a.f$$Parcelable is generated by Parceler.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When minify is true then also proguard is used which rewrites names. To keep it in original version add it to proguard.cfg files, example:

```
-keep class com.example.Patient.** { *; }
```

You can also make it easier with following rule:

```
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

it makes all the classes implementing Parcelable, have their CREATOR fileds kept non obfuscated. See here: [Do I need to 'keep' Parcelable in proguard rules while obfuscating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076826/do-i-need-to-keep-parcelable-in-proguard-rules-while-obfuscating)

Comment: Thanks marcinj for helping me! do i have to put this rule for all my objects?

Comment: oh nice, I really appreciate your help, thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Although the documentation says you have to put these lines to the Gradle:

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
```

change it to:

```
compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
kapt 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
```

Make sure all files you want to use are annotated with @Parcel.

I have class `First` with class `Second` variable and I forgot to annotate class `Second`. That's why changing from annotationProcessor to apt gives me a build error.

also, Don't forget to add `-keep class com.example.Patient.** { *; }` in your proguard file

Comment: Thanks GreenROBO for helping me! do i have to put this rule for all my objects?
whats the difference pron annotationProcessor to apt?

Comment: @GreenTOBO, i mean, all my classes that implements Parcelable shoud have a rule like that?

Comment: @Shermano see [marcinj's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57097940/1371792)

Comment: @Shermano you can upvote & accept if it has helped you. So it will be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: Yeah I did, I accepted @macninj answer tho sorry. Wish I could accept both, your answer was great as well