# Problem with kotlin parcelize and proguard rules

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I have this class:

```
@Parcelize
data class UserData(val name: String = "", val country: String = ""):Parcelable
```

In the proguard rules i have:

```
-keep class com.example.app.model.UserData
```

Then i use this in the repo (from Firebase):

```
val userdata = firestoreDoc.toObject(UserData::class.java)
```

If i disable `minifyEnabled` it works fine and `userData` gets populated, but when i enable it, it returns an empty `UserData` object.

I noticed that if i add the `@Keep` annotation to the UserData class it works as expected but i don't understand why.

Doesn't the proguard rules already keep the class?
Do i need to add a rule for kotlin parcelize?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I faced a similar issue. I think the reason is, that Kotlin classes are converted into java classes, named "UserDataKt" for UserData.kt. I think proguard is not capable of distinguishing between Java and Kotlin, and therefore the keep instruction doesn't work.

Comment: The reason could be that Parcelize plugin generates additional classes, you can check decompiled code of your Kotlin class in Android Studio. If you want to have rules without the Keep annotation see the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36076888/1635488

Comment: I believe you need to specify to keep the class members as well, i.e.

`-keep class com.example.app.model.UserData { *; }`

Still, I would recommend just using the `@Keep` annotation, personally.